# Orchard authorization is dropped sometimes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, orchardcms

When i work in dashboard (edit content items or settings) sometimes i am redirected to login page.

It happens only on a virtual hosting. There is memory limit of 1280 Mb. So, Sometimes, iis logger gives log event:

1. A worker process with process id of '49292' serving application pool '...' has requested a recycle because it reached its virtual memory limit.
2. A worker process serving application pool '...' has requested a recycle because it reached its private bytes memory limit.

I don't now if drop of authorization happens because of memory limit. But on my local machine with same limit and same log event all works fine.

How can i fix drop of authorization? And why does it may happen?

Comment: Drop of authorization happens because of memory limit... Maybe there is an IIS setting but definitely it is not Orchard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1280MB should be about 4 times what an Orchard instance needs under ordinary circumstances, so the first thing to do is probably to take a memory profile and find out what's eating so much memory. You very likely have a memory leak somewhere. This is the problem you should be focusing on: appdomain restarts are expensive and leave your application unresponsive for seconds.

Now yes, that still shouldn't drop authorization, which makes me think that you also have a misconfigured server. Most likely, you didn't configure a machine key, causing a new one to be generated at each restart, which makes existing authentication tokens invalid.

But really, your real problem is that memory footprint.

Comment: Changing machine key solved the problem with authorization.